# How to show a banner div on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, banner

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g39mc/)

As you can see in the demo, I'm showing a banner on clicking the link. Along with showing and hiding my banner `div`, I want to show my banner on mouseover (like a dropdown) to show users what is there, before they click the link.

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="show_hide">One</a>

<div class="slidingDiv" >
    <img src="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/images/home/spring.jpg" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     $(".slidingDiv").hide();
     $(".show_hide").show();

     $('.show_hide').click(function () {
         $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
         return false;
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to display *like* a dropdown, add `position:absolute` to the `.slidingDiv`

```
.slidingDiv {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

And change `.click` to `.hover`

See the example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/g39mc/11/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $(".slidingDiv").hide();
     $(".show_hide").show();

     $('.show_hide').on('mouseover',function () {
         $(".slidingDiv").show();
     });
     $('.show_hide').on('mouseleave',function () {
         $(".slidingDiv").hide();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did an example with jQuery Animate.

HTML

```
    <a id="myLink" href="#">One</a>

    <div id="slidingDiv">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#slidingDiv img{
   margin: 0 0 0 0;
   position: absolute;
   height: 0px;
   width: 100px;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
```

jQuery 1.10.1

```
    var toggleDiv = function( selector, height, width, marginBottom, opacity, time ){
            $(selector)
                .removeAttr('style')
                .stop().animate({
                    'height': height,
                    'width': width,
                    'marginBottom': marginBottom, 
                    'opacity': opacity 
                }, time, 'swing', function(){ console.log('Done!!'); } );
            };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var myImg = $( 'img', '#slidingDiv' ),
            myLink = $( '#myLink' );

        $( myImg ).hide();
        $( myLink )
            .on('mouseenter', function(){ toggleDiv( myImg, '100px', '100px', '30px', 1, 10 ) })
            .on('mouseleave', function() { toggleDiv( myImg, '0px', '100px', '0px', 0, 10 ) });
     });
```

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JuantxoCruz/40gLujj4/)!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `hover` instead of `click`:

```
 $('.show_hide').hover(function () {
     $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
     return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `click` to `hover` will do the trick.

```
$('.show_hide').hover(function () {
     $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
     return false;
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g39mc/2/)**

Comment: but this is affecting the content present below.. is there any way to show like dropdown

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. From the way you worded your question, this provides a solution to what you asked for - it shows the banner on mouseover.

Comment: Ok, I think you are asking for bind "click" and "hover" both event handlers simultaneously. Please check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g39mc/14/. But it's didn't a good approach, because when you click the item you already hovered it.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle

[Updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g39mc/5/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $(".slidingDiv").hide();
     $(".show_hide").show();

     $('.show_hide').on('mouseover',function () {
         $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
         return false;
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the best approach:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $(".slidingDiv").hide();
     $(".show_hide").show();

     $('.show_hide').on('mouseover mouseout',function () {
         $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

     });

 });
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g39mc/5/)

Answer (score 0):

try this
**JS**

```
 $(function(){
      $(".slidingDiv").hide();
         $(".show_hide").show();

         $('.show_hide').hover(function () {
             $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

         });
    });
```

And Add This To Your `CSS`

```
.slidingDiv {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position:absolute;
}
.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/j36Tj/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use hover

```
$('.show_hide').hover(function () {
 $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
 return false;
});
```